# FFMPEG trim command with amix

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am mixing two wav files together with amix. When I do the following with "-ss 50" it works. the first input wav is trimmed by 50ms. However when I do "-ss 0.100" (anything above 0.095), the trim seems to be ignored, its as though the "-ss" is not present

```
-y -ss 00:00:00.100 -i beat.wav -i vocal.wav -filter_complex [0:a]volume=0.8[a0];[1:a]volume=1.0[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest[fc] -map [fc] -ac 2 combinedbeatandvocal.wav
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Note that -ss 50 trims by 50 seconds, not 50 ms.

Comment: yes, "-ss 00:00:00.50" is what i use for 50 milliseconds

Comment: can you think why it might do this?

Comment: `00:00:00.50` is 500 milliseconds. The format is decimal, not lexical.

Comment: ahh yes, so 0.050 would be 50 ms. In my tests I'm actually using "00:00:00.500", "00:00:00.300" and "00:00:00.200" (500ms, 300ms and 200ms)